# Refresh a Sitecore rendering after logon

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-mvc

I feel like this should be obvious, but I'm stumped. We're running Sitecore 7.1 with MVC.

There is a Header rendering that includes conditional logic depending on the status of `Sitecore.Context.IsLoggedIn`. Works fine.

There is a second rendering that either allows the user to log in OR displays account information.  When the `[HttpGet]` acton is called, the controller checks `IsLoggedIn` and returns one of two views.  When the `[HttpPost]` action is called (i.e. when the user logs in),   The controller calls `AuthenticationManager.Login()` and then returns the view with the account info. Works fine.

It's a simple solution that allows us to place one rendering on the page, and it works great, except for one thing: the header rendering still shows the not-logged-in content immediately after logging in.

Caching is turned off on the header rendering and in the presentation details.  When any link is clicked or the page reloads, the header updates to show the correct info.  The problem is only after the initial request/response, when the login form submits and returns an alternate view. Although we've had a complete HTTP request/response cycle, it's like Sitecore doesn't bother to check anything except the rendering that was directly affected.

I know I can solve this by returning a hard Redirect() after logging in but that seems inelegant and creates annoyances, like losing ViewBag info.

What I am really looking for is a way to tell Sitecore, "hey, refresh that other rendering!"

The fact that I can find nothing at all on-line about this 'problem' tells me I might be doing something conceptually wrong.

Comment: Most likely the issue is the order that the logic fires, and the the problem is that the header is rendered/output before the login logic has been run. Try re-order the header control to be below the Login rendering in Presentation Details, does that solve the issue?

Comment: @jammykam, The order of the renderings in the presentation details won't matter.  It renders an entire placeholder in helper method call.  So if you built out a tree of the placeholders and renderings, it would render in depth-first order.

Comment: @BenGolden Ah, yes, you are right, I missed that. So perhaps a simpler solution would be as you suggested with AJAX but to refresh the page on success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at Jeremy's approach:
https://jermdavis.wordpress.com/2016/04/04/getting-mvc-components-to-communicate/

The key takeaway,  I think, is where he switches the order of the placeholders by placing the results into variables and then render them wherever you want them.

```
@{
    HtmlString main = Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("MAIN");
    HtmlString head = Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("HEAD");
}
<head>
    @head
</head>

<body>
    @main
</body>
```

Comment: That is one brilliant and ugly hack if ever there were one.  It also gets the job done in 4 lines of code.  Thanks for finding and calling out the important bits.

Answer (score 3):

As I see it there are two ways of handling this problem:

#### FormHandler

You use @Html.FormHandler to specify a Controller and an Action to handle the authentication. The FormHandler action will execute very early (see: https://twitter.com/dmo_sc/status/480001473745399809) in the page execution, before anything is rendered, and all your Renderings will have the same view of whether users are logged in or not.

Martina did a good writeup on Sitecore MVC and forms:

https://mhwelander.net/2014/05/28/posting-forms-in-sitecore-mvc-part-1-view-renderings/

https://mhwelander.net/2014/05/30/posting-forms-in-sitecore-mvc-part-2-controller-renderings/

#### Post-Redirect-Get

I really want Sitecore MVC to have this feature build in, as it is useful for all form submission scenarios (bar AJAX). The idea is to handle the POST request and work out what you want to respond (and store this in tempdata). Instead of returning a ViewResult you issue a redirect to the same URL, this forces a GET to the page (at this point all the logged in state is same for all Renderings) where you fish the result out of tempdata. Also P-R-G protects against resubmitting POST requests.

cprakash documented his experience doing P-R-G:

https://cprakash.com/2015/01/12/sitecore-mvc-form-post-simplified/

#### Off Topic: Multiple forms on single page

This will not solve the OP problem, but worth having a look at in this context:

http://reinoudvandalen.nl/blog/ultimate-fix-for-multiple-forms-on-one-page-with-sitecore-mvc/

Comment: Tried the P-R-G model next but TempData isn't persisting; seems to be a Sitecore issue.  Gah.  I just need to pass a flag that "this happened" for a welcome popup.  I'm stuck with contemplating a URL param.

Comment: Also trying the FormHandler stuff from Martina's post.  Getting weird errors, possible because of weirdness in my code base.  And yes, I did realize that we have a second form (search bar) in the Header. So that could well be it.

Answer (score 1):

In MVC, your renderings are executed sequentially, top to bottom.  So if your header rendering comes before the login status rendering, it's going to be done before the user is logged in.

The elegant way to do this would probably be to do your post and update both elements via JavaScript.  If you want to keep the header logic separate from the login status logic, your login status script could allow other components to register their own callbacks.  You could even build out a client-side message bus, if you will be doing this sort of thing frequently.

Comment: It seems you're correct, but "executed sequentially" includes the order in which placeholders are encountered.  The "controls" list in Device Editor only makes a difference when you have multiple renderings in the same placeholder. I have a "header" placeholder and a "content" placeholder. If I move my header rendering to bottom of the "content" placeholder it works.  If it is in the "header" placeholder it never works, no matter the order of the list.  Kind of an impossible situation, since headers need to go at the top of the page.

Comment: Marked "useful" for correctly calling out the problem with rendering sequence, even if I didn't want to build a JS messaging bus.  :-) Thanks!